# ESP32 / M5Core2 updating time for DST

Tags: arduino, esp32, dst, ntp

I'd like to have the time automatically adjust for Daylight Saving time without having to do an NTP update.  The Core2 device uses a BM8563 RTC chip.
The following function sets my timezone and DST correctly when it does an NTP update. But when the DST start or end time arrives the time is not adjusted until I do another NTP update. The device will be running without access to an NTP server after initial setup.

I'd be grateful for any observations and suggestions.

```
#include <M5Core2.h>

RTC_TimeTypeDef TimeStruct;
RTC_DateTypeDef DateStruct;
struct tm timeinfo;
const char* timezone = "AEST-10AEDT,M10.1.0,M4.1.0/3";
const char* ntpServer = "au.pool.ntp.org";

   // WiFI is already connected

bool timeSync() {
  configTime(0, 0, ntpServer); // get UTC time from NTP server
  setenv("TZ", timezone, 1); // Set the TZ.
  tzset();
  if (!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)) {
    Serial.print("Failed to obtain time from ");
    Serial.println(ntpServer);
    return false;
  }
// Copy the time and date from the struct tm format into the M5Core2
// TimeStruct and write it into the RTC.
  TimeStruct.Hours = timeinfo.tm_hour;
  TimeStruct.Minutes = timeinfo.tm_min;
  TimeStruct.Seconds = timeinfo.tm_sec;
  DateStruct.Year = (timeinfo.tm_year + 1900);
  DateStruct.Month = (timeinfo.tm_mon + 1);
  DateStruct.Date = timeinfo.tm_mday;
  DateStruct.WeekDay = timeinfo.tm_wday; // day of week. 0 = Sunday

  // TimeStruct.Hours = 2;
  // TimeStruct.Minutes = 58;
  // DateStruct.Month = 4;
  // DateStruct.Date = 3;
  // DateStruct.WeekDay = 0;
  M5.Rtc.SetTime(&TimeStruct);
  M5.Rtc.SetDate(&DateStruct);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: The BM8563 chip does not have the concept of timezone or daylight saving, so it is your responsibility to adjust it.

Comment: @hcheung ok thanks for the reply. I suspected that may have been the case.

Comment: It's weird. Theoretically libc should be aware of daylight saving time and the complicated timezone string you've added should specify the transition times. But it looks like this doesn't work quite as effortlessly in the background as one might imagine.

Comment: By the way, I think you didn't set the daylight saving correctly. The `configTime()` take in a timezone offset and daylight saving offset as `configTime(long gmtOffset_sec, int daylightOffset_sec, const char* server)`, the `setEnv()` and `tzset()` are called internally, see the [source code](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-time.c#L48). For your timezone, the usage should be `configTime(3600*11, 3600, ntpServer).

Comment: @hcheung the code as it is works for setting the timezone and DST from an NTP update. If I use `configTime(0, 0, ntpServer)` without the `setenv` and `tzset` I just get the current time in UTC. Doing the `setenv` and `tzset` then changes the timezone and DST according to the timezone string. Doing it the way you suggest would also work.

Comment: `configTime(0, 0, ntpServer)` set to UTC time, without daylight saving, `configTIme(3600*11, 3600, ntpServer)` set to to UTC+11 timezone, with daylight saving of +/-1 hour.